# 400 Bad request CSRF Angular 8 with no razor pages

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-3.1

Error: 400 Bad request.

I have no razor pages like layout.cshtml, angular app is running seprate and .net core api running seperate. having an issue with anti forgery tokens.

followed below instructions none of the worked.
[Anti forgery with token API and angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086456/anti-forgery-with-token-api-and-angular)

[How to validate AntiForgeryToken issued from one Application on different Application in .NetCore API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439732/how-to-validate-antiforgerytoken-issued-from-one-application-on-different-applic)
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1343/aspnet-core-csrf-antiforgery-token
[.net Core 2.0 web api 400 error using Validateantiforgerytoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508092/net-core-2-0-web-api-400-error-using-validateantiforgerytoken)

tried:

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
                if (path != null && path.ToLower().Contains("/api"))
                {
                    // XSRF-TOKEN used by angular in the $http if provided
                    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN",
                      tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
                      {
                          HttpOnly = false,
                          Secure = false
                      }
                    ); ;
                }


                await next();
            });
```

The above links shows only the angular app running inside layout.cshtml.
In the angular request added XSRF token

```
 @Injectable()
    export class XsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {}

    private actions: string[] = ["POST", "PUT", "DELETE"];
    private forbiddenActions: string[] = ["HEAD", "OPTIONS"];

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
        let permitted =  this.findByActionName(request.method, this.actions);
        let forbidden =  this.findByActionName(request.method, this.forbiddenActions);;

        if (permitted !== undefined && forbidden === undefined && token !== null) {
            request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token } });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }

    private findByActionName(name: string, actions: string[]): string {
        return actions.find(action => action.toLocaleLowerCase() === name.toLocaleLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Request Header

[image]

Comment: You say you have an issue with your CSRF tokens but you don't actually say what your issue _is_.

Comment: simple : i am using angular 8 app , i have added csrf token in request header ,the csrf token is reside in application cookies tab. and i have added the suggested solution in .net core middleware,  getting a  bad request as 400. pls, look through the link and above code and link for better understanding.

Comment: @ Roddy of the Frozen Peas  same problem he mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555043/asp-net-core-2-2-and-angular-implementation-of-antiforgerytoken-badrequest-error

Comment: All code, stack traces, and problems should be in the post itself, not spread across multiple links. And the way to get more attention to another post is to put a bounty on it, not post a duplicate.